# mysql triggers using vs select query

Tags: mysql

I use mysql trigger to update column in one of ,y DB tables called comments_count but I want to know what is best and faster??

Using mysql triggers or select query like this below:

```
select count(*) from comments where discussion_id=something
```

Comment: Storing the count separately means it's possible for the count to become out of sync with the actual number of comments. How are you prepared to deal with that? – Whenever possible you should derive derivable data as needed, not store it somewhere (meaning `SELECT COUNT` when necessary). Is there any specific concern why you don't want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

different types of overhead:

with the trigger you will have extra time during insert, and may get out of synch over time for some unforseen reason.

with the query, you will always get the right answer but you will need to calculate at runtime.  usually, this should be very fast especially with an index on the discussion_id

Comment: Do you mean I should use query??

Comment: well there are the trade offs listed - but yes - for me, I would use the query.